# Magento - Changes to Edit Account Information screen do not get reflected

Tags: magento, themes

I have my custom theme, in which I would like to make changes to the Edit Account Information Screen. I have tried to modify this file:

*customer/form/edit.phtml*

No change that I make to this file gets reflected. I even removed all customer/form/edit.phtml files from the base and my custom theme. Even then, the screen renders.

This is the relevant code in my customer.xml file:

```
<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Edit Form</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Edit Account Info</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/form_edit" name="customer_edit" template="customer/form/edit.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.permanent.callout</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was happening. I have an extension installed which has the following code:

```
<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="head.calendar" as="html_calendar" template="aitcheckoutfields/js/calendar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="customer_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>aitcommonfiles/design--frontend--base--default--template--customer--form--edit.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

I commented out this code and now my edit.phtml is being used to render the form. I still do not understand, however, which phtml file this refers to?

Comment: From that it looks like the file you're looking for is probably `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/aitcommonfiles/design--frontend--base--default--template--customer--form--edit.phtml`. Use [template hints](http://www.topinternetguides.com/blog/2008/05/26/magento-tutorial-turning-on-template-path-hints/) to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Aitoc sometimes uses a funky rewrite method to generate template files for their modules. I had the same issue and eventually found my .phtml file in  /var/ait_patch/design/frontend/default/default/template/aitcommonfiles

Answer (score 0):

When files are missing from your custom theme the template system falls back to the equivalent files in the default/base theme. Also, Magento caches this so when new files are introduced it won't notice straight away and continue using the base files instead. Make sure you turn off all caches when developing.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I do have caching disabled.